# How to fix script after upgrading jQuery to 2.1.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using jQuery 1.8.3 and had this piece of script :

```
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../Images/minus.gif");
    });

    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "../Images/plus-sign.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

After upgrading to jQuery 2.1.4, this no longer works.

I get it that some functions like `live` is not supported anymore but I am unable to convert this piece to make it work.

Comment: try changing `live` to `on`

Comment: `live` was depreciated & now removed in latest stable version of JQuery. use `on` instead.

Comment: already tried that but it is still not working

Comment: does the console show any errors? Can you include the relevant html?

Comment: @ash_dev15 Can you provide the sample of code in which you tried using `.on` as a replacement for `.live`?

Comment: Switching to `on` should work, but you also forgot a semicolon on the second line.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle using `.on` with your sample code.](http://jsfiddle.net/910twf0t/)

Comment: What browser are you using for testing?

Answer (score 2):

When upgrading jQuery you should use [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

This is [offically recommended](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) way in finding out what has been deprecated in jQuery.

> If you’re upgrading from a version before 1.9, we recommend that you
>   use the jQuery Migrate plugin and read the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide,
>   since there have been a lot of changes. It’s easy to use the plugin,
>   just include it in your HTML file after jQuery and open your browser
>   console to see the messages it generates:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
> ```

You should also look into the [jQuery upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

Answer (score 1):

[`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.